# send GET request with json body in flutter

Tags: json, api, http, flutter, dart

I need to send a GET request to an API from my flutter application, with json parameters in the body. I've googled it (maybe I've not googled it so well), But a lot of people have this problem of sending a GET request with JSON body in flutter.
When I try the request in POSTMAN it work.

```
var url = 'linkofapi;


var response = await http.get(url);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, first of all, `GET` operations are not intended to send the data. It is meant to receive the data, hence the method name `GET`, hence `http.get()` doesn't have a `body`.

If sending the data is the utmost requirement, then you need to use `Uri` to add a `query parameter` to the `http` method.

Please read about [Uri.http](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html) flutter for more information.

You can do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
// Please note "...." for more information, please do not use this as is
// Just wanted to give a heads up
final query = {
  'name': your_name,
  'email': your_email,
  'password': your_password
  ...
};

var url = 'linkofapi;

// Now you use the query to pass it to. your get method
final uri = Uri.http(url, '/path', query);
// adding headers to the query
final header = {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'};
// doing the operation finally
final response = await http.get(uri, headers: header);
```

Comment: I need to pass data in body not in url

Comment: I tried this   final uri = Uri.http(url, '', query);  because I don't need to pass params in url.But it dosen't work

Comment: "I need to pass data in body not in url" - Then it's not a "GET".

Comment: "it's a GET request with json in body like you see in the image".  And that's not valid. GET must not have a body.

Comment: We call that "an invalid way to construct an HTTP request".  GET does not have a body.  Period.  Stop busting the spec.

Comment: What part of "just because POSTMAN is ignoring a part of the spec" are you not understanding?  GET does not have a body.  Period.  You should not make up random things to go across the wire.  Please stop.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks bro, I was wrong. It was my first experience with the HTTP request, now I understand what you said .Thanks again bro

Comment: You should see the scars I have for what I've gotten wrong over the years. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Future<http.Response> createUser({name, email, password, gender, dob}) {
  return http.get(
    'http://$BASE_API_URL/users',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'gender': gender,
      'dob': dob,
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: it's says that the named parameter 'body' isn't defined

Comment: I used it like this  response = http.get(
    'http://$BASE_API_URL/users',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'gender': gender,
      'dob': dob,
    }),
  );

Comment: It is not an answer my friend. Please consider editing it, cos `http.get()` doesn't have a body.